# What are different methods to import/export client data in Openbravo?

Tags: openbravo

I'd like to know if there are different ways to import / export client data in Openbravo. The built-in import client doesn't work well when we have a client with large data.

Answer (score 1):

There are three different ways you can bring in the client into the new system.

**1. Binary Database Dump**

```
 `* pg_dump dbname > outfile`

 `* psql -U postgres -f outfile dbname `
```

**2. Using Import/Export UI provided by Openbravo (not for production)**

- This client export should only be used for smaller datasets and for
  development purposes. It should not be used in production
  environments with large amounts of data since its XML format is not
  designed for such a purpose.
- However, for production purposes, a    binary dump of the database
  should be used.

**3.ant install.source (The export client UI will be used here.)**

- In order to be automatically imported the clients data, the xml files should be moved from referencedata/importclient to referencedata/sampledata

[Click here for more information](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/ERP_2.50%3aOracle_to_PostgreSQL_migration#Import)

hope this helps you !..